# "Default\anonymous" user's "read" access gets automatically set to "Deny" when certain items are previewed

Tags: content-management, permissions

Using `Sitecore 10.2` on a scaled environment that has 1 CM.

The issue is that, for a few specific old items, and for any newly created item, "previewing" the item does 3 things:

1. Sets the read access for the item to "Deny" automatically for the
   `default\anonymous` user
2. doesn't preview the item itself and redirects to the homepage
3. Logs the following error:

> ERROR Item could not be found from query string. [ID is
> "{156F03CA-E1EF-45A8-841B-A409CE466A3E}".]

This behavior does not happen for all the old items, only for these specific items (which are duplicates of existing old items, for example ContactUs page previews fine, but copy of ContactUs page has this issue).

Tried lots of different scenarios to make sure what triggers the permission change, wanted to check its not the `workflow`, or the `publishing`, and confirmed it always happens on preview specifically.

Issue doesn't happen if I explicitly give the item "read" access in the security editor, but it happens if I keep the permissions neutral, where it inherits the read access from the home root item

The `"default\anonymous"` user that is used by Sitecore to preview the item keeps getting its permissions set to deny and I am not sure what is causing it.

I've looked at the custom code in the solution for any custom pipelines related to preview, didn't find anything,
I've also checked that the parent node of the site has read access applied to the anonymous user (and all the items of the site inherit from it).

Any ideas what could cause this?